# Is it possible to replicate a transaction deadlock in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, transactions, deadlock

In SQL it is relatively easy to replicate a transaction deadlock.

```
==SESSION1==
begin tran
update table1 set ... where ...
[hold off further action - begin on next session]

==SESSION2==
begin 
update table1 set ... where ...
[hold off further action - begin on next session]

==SESSION3==
<list blocked transactions - see session2>
```

Now with Clojure transactions - you can't just open them and leave them open, the s-expressions don't let you do that.

So I'm curious with respect to the scenario above.

My question is: **Is it possible to replicate a transaction deadlock in Clojure?**

Comment: Deadlocks can't happen. Livelocks can. In any case you have to spawn two threads and use synchronization mechanisms to enforce a scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STM in Clojure is designed to provide atomic, consistent and isolated actions on refs, *without* locking. Several features are implemented in order to achieve this as described in [refs documentation](http://clojure.org/refs), but one of the main point is to have a "optimistic" strategy, which handles version of data for each transaction and compare this version and the ref version at write time.

This kind of optimistic strategy can be implemented in database as well, e.g. in [Oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/papers/locking.pdf).

Anyway, in Clojure, if you really want to create a deadlock, you will have to use low level mecanism, for instance the `locking` macro that explicitly create a lock on an object (same as `synchronized` in Java) and manage explicitly the access to the shared resource.

EDIT : Example of *livelock*
This example comes from *Clojure Programming*, @cgrand and al.

```
(let [retry-count (agent 0)
      x (ref 0)]
  (try
    (dosync  ;; transaction A
      @(future (dosync ;; transaction B
                 (send-off retry-count inc)
                 (ref-set x 1)))
      (ref-set x 2))
    (catch Exception e (println (str "caught exception: " (.getMessage e))))
    (finally
    (await retry-count)))
  [@x @retry-count])

caught exception: Transaction failed after reaching retry limit
[1 10000]
user>
```

Transaction A executes in the repl thread. Transaction B will execute in a separate thread, but since the `future` is deref in A, it blocks until B finishes. When A tries `(ref-set x 2)`, x has already been modified by B, and this trigger a retry of A, which spawn a new thread and B transaction... until the maximum retries is reached and an exception raised.

Comment: That's interesting. Could I just do a (Thread/sleep 1000) in the middle of my first Clojure transaction (running in a future) and have it block the second Clojure transaction? (ie surely the locking macro isn't actually required?)

Comment: Actually, the second transaction won't be really blocked, but it will retry until the first one finishes _or_ the limit of retries is reach (some hardcoded constant : 10000). I will edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @T.Gounelle in what moment transaction A will realize that the value of `x` was changed by another transaction? I mean at want moment transaction A get the `ref` of x?

Answer (score 0):

According to Rich Hickey:

> Clojure's STM and agent mechanisms are deadlock-free. They are not message-passing systems with blocking selective receive. The STM uses locks internally, but does lock-conflict detection and resolution automatically.

More details can be found in [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/DBkKs7SiPj4) group.